# Creating a range from a dynamic row and setting number format to percentage in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a range from a dynamic row. I have the following:

```
Set mytestrange = ThisSheet.Range("I" & (GrossProfitMarginRow) & ":XX" & (GrossProfitMarginRow))
mytestrange.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
```

GrossProfitMarginRow is 16 and I wish to set all cells on the row between column I and column XX to have a percentage format of 0.0%. Unfortunately the above doesn't work. Is there a different approach to this?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Btw, the parentheses around `GrossProfitMarginRow` are redundant.

Comment: do you mean the range construction looks correct and in your test it sets the format correctly?

Comment: That's right. Something else is missing from your question (e.g. how you assign `ThisSheet` or how you determine `GrossProfitMarginRow`, or if the worksheet is protected, or if the values in that range are text and not numbers).

Comment: The values in the range are determined by a spill formula in I16. If I clearFormats first it does set the format but the percentages are larger than I expected. I'll do some digging in to this.

Comment: Can you advise what doesn't work? Where does it fail? What happens when you run it? Are you getting an error, and on what line? Stuff like that? Are you running code that copies and pastes after this? If so, your code may be working, but then it's overwriting the format you set with a paste downstream of a different format. Sorry for all the questions, just not sure there's enough info here to understand your issue.

Comment: turns out the percentage issue was something wrong with the actual formula so clearing the formatting and then setting it fixed the issue with it not accepting the formatting

Answer (score 0):

calling mytestrange.ClearFormats before setting the formatting fixed the issue with the formatting not displaying in the range.